# Unable to use RCurl in R on Windows

Tags: r, curl, rcurl, rentrez

I have installed curl from [this weblink](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html). I have my system path also updated with curl install directory and I am able to curl from the command prompt. I have also installed RCurl. But, my RStudio throws this error:

> Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘curl’

My code is as follows;

```
#install.packages("RCurl")
#install.packages("Biostrings")
#install.packages("rentrez")
library(Biostrings)
library(RCurl)
library(rentrez)

seq1 <- entrez_fetch(db = "sequences", rettype = 'fasta', id = "187830855") #human
```

I am using the latest R and RStudio on a Windows 8.1 machine.

Comment: I think you may need to install the `curl` package (that is, the R package named `curl`). According to CRAN, `rentrez` imports `httr` which imports `curl` not `RCurl`.

Comment: Thanks. That fixed the problem. I had actually two curl(s) in my libraries and one was a source file. When RStudio asked which one to use I selected the other one and it started running.

The difference was between the kinds of curl I had one was a dev the other was a source file without the "-dev" in it.